# Подсветка кода в Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Привет, сообщество. Вопрос, возможно, уже не раз задавался. Поскольку я не могу нормально загуглить и найти ответ, то напишу сюда.

Собственно сам вопрос: как отключить фоновую подсветку кода в Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate для web-приложений, чтобы код фона C# был тем же, что и фон HTML, а именно в файле где пишется код HTML & C# (.cshtml). Для примера оставлю картинку.

[image]

Comment: Мне не очень удобно так, хотя может быть со временем привыкну

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы код фона C# был тем же, что и фон HTML вам нужно задать такой же цвет как фон страницы cshtml.
Заходим в

> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Display Items

Нас интересует `Html Razor Code BackGround`. изменяем цвет на нужный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]